# Win32/Gdigrab - How to set another process window as borderless?

Tags: c++, winapi, video-capture

I am currently using GDIGRAB to capture a window. The problem is, because of the border, the mouse cursor has an offset on its position.

The idea is to put a window as borderless so the offset won't appear anymore. Given the handle of the aimed process, how can I change a window from windowed to borderless ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't tinker with another process' windows. Instead, get the border offset.

```
HWND window = ...;
RECT wndRect, clientRect;
GetWindowRect(window,&wndRect);
GetClientRect(window,&clientRect);
POINT borderOffset={clientRect.left,clientRect.top};
ClientToScreen(window,&borderOffset);
borderOffset.x-=wndRect.left;
borderOffset.y-=wndRect.top;
// borderOffset now contains the x and y offsets for the window
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found a way by making the process window as borderless using the win32 api.